# Пауза в выполнении функции C#

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Занимаюсь созданием эмулятора консоли. Поле ввода сделано как TextBox и команды обрабатываются по событию PreviewKeyDown текстбокса (по нажатию Enter). После обработки команда должна выдавать строковый результат и выводить его в textBox. Все бы было ничего, если бы не появилась необходимость создать тип команд, который требует дополнительного пользовательского ввода, например, некоторые команды должны требовать определенных привилегий, сокрытых админским паролем.

Вот упрощенный вид того, что я пытаюсь сделать:

```
private string expectUserInput( string inviteString ) {
    CLI_TextBox.Text += "\r\n" + inviteString;
    CLI_TextBox.CaretIndex = CLI_TextBox.Text.Length;

    return "some result";
}

private string enable( ) {
    string password = expectUserInput("Password: ");
    // If password is correct - do some staff;
    return "someStaffResult";
}

private void CLI_TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        string result;
        string lineContent = CLI_TextBox.GetLineText(CLI_TextBox.GetLastVisibleLineIndex());
        if (lineContent == "enable") {
            result = enable();
        }

    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Моя задумка (ну или по крайней мере гипотетическая идея) заключается в том, что бы сделать функцию **expectUserInput()** как бы ожидающей определенного события (в моем случае это опять же нажатие на клавишу Enter, но правда на это событие уже есть свой обработчик), и пока это событие не наступит, она не выполнится, и не выполнится **enable()**. Перелопатил гугл, но так решения и не нашел. Понял только, что копать нужно в сторону *async/await* и генерации собственных событий (возможно), но как это применить в данной ситуации не совсем пойму. Возможно кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой и находил успешное ее решение?

Comment: явно ждать не обязательно. в обработчике события можно запомнить его в списке событий, при следующем вызове обработчика проверить список событий

Comment: Простите, но я не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду под списком событий в обработчике. И то как их различать при вызове обработчика. Может поясните или пример приведете?

Comment: в классе определяете переменную: `int mode=0;`. все нажатия обрабатываете в CLI_TextBox_PreviewKeyDown. если mode==0, то обрабатываете все как обычно. но если требуется дополнительный ввод, то ставите `mode=1`, и в этом режиме "ждете" специальные нажатия. как только получите его, переходите в `mode=0` или еще какой-нибудь.

Comment: @Stack, возможно я не совсем ясно описал свою проблему. Мне нужно, чтобы выполнение функции `enable()` запаузилось до тех пор, пока не будет выполнена функция `expectUserInput()`, которая, в свою очередь, тоже не выполняется, пока не наступит определенное событие.

Comment: _"нужно, чтобы выполнение функции enable() запаузилось"_ -- события происходят в UI потоке, его паузить нельзя. в обработчиках вы можете просто переключать режим работы. сделайте state machine и просто по разному реагируйте на нажатия.

Comment: Ждать чего?  Если у вас однопоточная программа - и вы ждёте "стечение" хороших обстоятельст - тогда моё предложение не ждать - а выставить в переменную статус ожидания и сделать return. Затем создать таймер-функцию (раз в пол-секунды),  проверять статус ожидания, и условие ожидания. Если все условия ОК - что-то выполнять. А функции ожидания используются в многопоточных системах, и ждут обычно или поток или готовность обьекта.

Comment: Вот здесь и должна идти речь об ожидании готовности объекта. Пошел курить мануалу по Task. Если получится сделать через него - выкину сюда решение.

Answer (score 1):

не совсем понял вопрос. но возможно вам поможет то что я недавно нашёл. можно ожидать определённого действия без блокировки основного потока

```
DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
//здесь подписываетесь на какое-либо событие и ожидаете
Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);

//в теле обработчика после определённых действий продолжаете выполнение программы
frame.Continue = false;
```